# pyFFTW doesn't find libfftw3l.so while import

Tags: python, path, pyfftw

In my Raspbian system I have succesfully installed pyFFTW, but there is a problem while import package.

```
  import pyfftw
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyfftw/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  from .pyfftw import ( 
ImportError: libfftw3l.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Actually, I have FFTW installed from source.

---

I've dig into __init__.py and there is an **relative import** line:

```
from .pyfftw import (
              FFTW
              blah blah )
```

there is no module pyfftw in the . folder but I suppose this line indicates to ./**pyfftw.cpython-34m.so** file which probably wraps C code of FFTW.

How to tell to this pyfftw.cpython-34m.so file where it should look for correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with PYTHONPATH.

To check if the file is somewhere at the disk:

```
$ sudo file / -name libfftw3l.so.3
/home/pi/bin/fftw-3.3.5/.libs/libfftw3.so.3
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfftw3.so.3
/usr/local/lib/libfftw3.so.3
```

And add a line before import pyfftw (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/libfftw3.so.3')
```

Comment: Really, that works? I understood that the long version of fftw wasn't supported on ARM. pyFFTW is not currently supported on ARM for this reason. See [this issue](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/127). If you want to help fix this, we're keen for input (it amounts to handling the missing libraries properly and raising suitable exceptions on the Python end).

Comment: Yes, it works. I saw this issue. I have reinstalled FFTW manually with enabled long double and float types. Than install pyFFTW by pip. I would glad to help but I am new in python and Im afraid it's beyond my scope